# Error while adding validator to reactive form

Tags: angular, validation, typescript

I have created a simple form to which I would like to add a validator:

```
 form;

  constructor() { 
    this.form = new FormGroup({
    'old-password' : new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)], PasswordValidators.checkPassword),
    'new-password' : new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]),
    'confirm-password' : new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])
  }, {
      validator: PasswordValidators.passwordsShouldMatch
    });
  }
```

But in `validator` section I get an error which says:

```
[ts]
Argument of type '{ validator: (control: AbstractControl) => { passwordsShouldMatch: boolean; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'validator' does not exist in type 'ValidatorFn'.
(property) validator: (control: AbstractControl) => {
    passwordsShouldMatch: boolean;
}
```

When I change the construction of the form to `FormBuilder` it starts to working - why's that?

Comment: did you try removing `validator:` just by mentioning your custom `validator`

Comment: Can you post `PasswordValidators.passwordsShouldMatch` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [api documentation and example](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#example-1) the constructor is just getting the validator function, not an object as `FormBuilder` does.

So this should work:

```
constructor() { 
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    'old-password' : new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)], PasswordValidators.checkPassword),
    'new-password' : new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]),
    'confirm-password' : new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])
  },
  PasswordValidators.passwordsShouldMatch
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about what the `PasswordValidators` object that you're using looks like but I rearranged your code to give you an example of the correct syntax that you should use in order to achieve what you want:

```
export class ModelDrivenForm {
  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
        oldpassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), this.checkPassword]),
        newpassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]),
        confirmpassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])
      },
      this.passwordsShouldMatch
    );
  }

  private checkPassword(control: FormControl) {
    return control.value.toString().length >= 5 && control.value.toString().length <= 10
      ? null
      : {'outOfRange': true};
  }

  private passwordsShouldMatch(fGroup: FormGroup) {
    return fGroup.get('password').value === fGroup.get('passwordConfirm').value
      ? null : {'mismatch': true};
  }
}
```

P.S: the `checkPassword` controls if the number of characters of the password is between `5` and `10` chars in the given example